# Jenkins not expanding macros

Tags: java, jenkins, macros

I hope that is the right lingo. I've been fighting this for about 2 days now.

#### TL;DR

My plugin I'm developing is not replacing macros like `%BUILD_NUMBER%` or `%JOB_NAME%`

#### Details

I'm making a notifier plugin for Jenkins that simply runs pickles on my specflow tests. (It generates a html report). I got all the configuration stuff figured out for both the ToolInstallation as well as the Notifier itself as a freestyle build step (I do have in place the workflow bits, but i've not tested that yet) This Notifier is replacing the builder step of running a windows batch file which is essentially this

```
C:\BuildTools\Pickles-2.10.0\pickles.exe ^
--feature-directory="%WORKSPACE%\My.Program.AcceptanceTests" ^
--output-directory="\\some-server\c$\Features\my-program" ^
--documentation-format=dhtml ^
--system-under-test-name="%JOB_NAME%" ^
--system-under-test-version="Build #%BUILD_NUMBER%" ^
--link-results-file="%WORKSPACE%\nunit-test-results\NUnitTestResults.xml" ^
--test-results-format=nunit
```

To replicate this I made a `BuildPicklesNotifierArguments` class.

```
package hudson.plugins.pickles.utilities;

import hudson.EnvVars;
import hudson.Util;
import hudson.plugins.pickles.PicklesNotifier;
import hudson.util.ArgumentListBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

public class BuildPicklesArguments {

    private final PicklesNotifier picklesArguments;
    private final Map<String, String> buildVariables;
    private final EnvVars env;

    public BuildPicklesArguments(PicklesNotifier picklesNotifier, Map<String, String> buildVariables, EnvVars env) {
        this.picklesArguments = picklesNotifier;
        this.buildVariables = buildVariables;
        this.env = env;
    }

    public void buildArguments(ArgumentListBuilder args){
        safeAdd(args, "feature-directory", picklesArguments.getFeatureDirectory());
        safeAdd(args, "output-directory", picklesArguments.getOutputDirectory());
        safeAdd(args, "documentation-format", picklesArguments.getDocumentationFormat());
        safeAdd(args, "system-under-test-name", picklesArguments.getSystemUnderTestName());
        safeAdd(args, "system-under-test-version", picklesArguments.getSystemUnderTestVersion());
        safeAdd(args, "link-results-file", picklesArguments.getLinkResultsFiles());
        safeAdd(args, "test-results-format", picklesArguments.getTestResultFormat());

        if(!picklesArguments.getEnableComments())
            args.add("--enableComments=false");
        if(picklesArguments.getIncludeExperimentalFeatures())
            args.add("--include-experimental-features");
    }

    private void safeAdd(ArgumentListBuilder args, String switchString, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            String expanded = Util.replaceMacro(value, env);
            expanded = Util.replaceMacro(expanded, buildVariables);
            args.addKeyValuePair("--", switchString, expanded, false);
//            args.addQuoted(String.format("--%s=\"%s\"", switchString, expanded));
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a unit test that shows the problem

```
package hudson.plugins.pickles.utilities;

import hudson.EnvVars;
import hudson.plugins.pickles.PicklesNotifier;
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty;
import hudson.util.ArgumentListBuilder;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class BuildPicklesArgumentsTest {
    @Test
    public void buildArguments() throws Exception {
        ArgumentListBuilder args = new ArgumentListBuilder();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("${BUILD_NUMBER}", "4");
        EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty prop = new EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
        EnvVars env = prop.getEnvVars();
        env.put("%BUILD_NUMBER%", "4");
        PicklesNotifier pickles = new PicklesNotifier();
        pickles.setSystemUnderTestVersion("Build #%BUILD_NUMBER%");
        pickles.setEnableComments(true);
        pickles.setIncludeExperimentalFeatures(false);
        BuildPicklesArguments build = new BuildPicklesArguments(pickles, map, env);

        build.buildArguments(args);

        assertEquals("\"--system-under-test-version=Build #4\"", args.toString());
    }
}
```

which fails:

```
Expected :"--system-under-test-version=Build #4"
Actual   :"--system-under-test-version=Build #%BUILD_NUMBER%"
```

I'm struggling with the test because I don't know exactly what the environment variables look like so I've tried many variations, but outcome is the same when running in Jenkins as the test results. Lastly out of curiosity I took out all of the macros in my configuration and rebuilt and it was successful (the command looked like this) `C:\BuildTools\Pickles-2.10.0\pickles.exe --feature-directory=My.Program.AcceptanceTests --output-directory=C:\temp\testpickles --documentation-format=dhtml --system-under-test-name=Freestylnit "--system-under-test-version=Build #5" --link-results-file=NunitTestResults.xml --test-results-format=nunit`. I'm glad it works because I thought the argument `system-under-test-version` was going to cause problems being wrapped in a double quote, but apparently that wasn't the problem. FYI if you want to see the rest of the source code [look at it in github](https://github.com/immeraufdemhund/pickles-notifier-plugin)

Comment: You should just be adding `BUILD_NUMBER` as the key to the `Map`/`EnvVars`, and not adding any symbols around them.